# modifying multipart headers when using the email library in python

Tags: python, email

I'm experimenting with email.mime to produce a variety of header configurations to be used when sending emails.

So far I've been using:-

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

to delete, add and modify headers. I'm now starting to try multipart headers and am using:-

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultiPart

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
text = 'add this text to the multipart'
textMIME = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
msg.attach(MIMEText)

text2 = 'add this text to the next multipart'
text2MIME = MIMEText(text2, 'plain')
msg.attach(MIME2Text)
```

It gives me an output similar to:-

```
Return-Path: xxxxx
X-Original-To: xxxxxxxxx
Delivered-To: xxxxxxx
Received: from xxxxxx
        to xxxxxxxxx
        for xxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="==========yyyyyyyy=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: xxxxxxx
Date: xxxxxx
From: xxxxx
To: xxxxx

--==========yyyyyyyy==
Content-Type: xxxxxxx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

add this text to the multipart

--==========yyyyyyyy==
Content-Type: xxxxxxx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

add this text to the next multipart
--==========yyyyyyyy==
```

which seems reasonable straight forward to use, except for a couple of things I can't work out.

What I cant work out is:-

1. How do I add text so that it appears after the 'To: xxxxx' header and before the first multipart boundary? When I use the msg.attach it first adds the default headers before writing the text. I also tried msg.add_header('', 'my text'), but that gave me the text in a header format i.e. ': my text' instead of just the plain text.
2. How do I specifically modify the multipart headers like 'Content-Type'? When I try to delete a header like 'Content-Type' (no matter where I put it in the code) it automatically deletes the first header value it finds, which is the first one 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="==========yyyyyyyy=="'. Is it possible to specify which header in a particular multipart to modify?

Thanks.